# Single word to mean how far behind something is

Tags: word-request

For example, if you have 3 tasks to do every period of time, but you manage to do only 2 in that time period. You're **falling behind**, but if you want to measure how far behind you are, what word could you use ? Is there a single word for that ?

If you wrote on a spreadsheet how many tasks you're behind, how would you name the file ?

"Lateness" and "delay" don't seem mean that, and I only find verbs in dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps *shortfall*?

Comment: How about **backlog**?

Comment: @TRomano Thank you this is exactly the word I'm looking for ! "*unprocessed items*", "*items in a queue*", that's it :)

Comment: An accumulation of work items that have not been completed.  I am very familiar with the situation. The word is always on the tip of my tongue.

Comment: @TRomano Wonderful... you should make your comment into an answer. Perhaps the question could be edited and I could if it not longer makes sense, delete my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **backlog** is an accumulation of uncompleted tasks.

Answer (score 3):

(from google definition) fall behind
phrasal verb of fall
1.
fail to keep up with one's competitors.
fail to meet a commitment to make a regular payment.
"borrowers falling behind with their mortgage payments"
synonyms:   **lag**, lag behind, **trail**, trail behind, be left behind, drop back, bring up the rear; **straggle, dally, dawdle**, hang back
"the other walkers fell behind"
get into debt, get into arrears, **default**, be in the red
"they fell behind on their payments"

Failed, To do list, Unfinished, [LINK: incomplete](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/incomplete)

'How far' to me means a measurement. I can not think of, nor can I find a single word that expresses the measurement in one word.

Comment: A measurement as in "how much" or "how far" ? Maybe I used the wrong word, "far" doesn't seem perfect, but if you had the "how [word]" for "falling behind" I wouldn't mind editing my title :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat How far to me means there would be a specific answer. How far behind are you?" Answer, "I need another hour." Or, "I'm a kilometre away." Or, "I have three more columns to finish." So you need to explain what you mean before you will get the answer. Is the work incomplete?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean ! If you can't say it in one word, how would you say it ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat How about *Incomplete*? Or *Partial*, *Unfinished*?  To be positive, try: *In Progress*, *Under way*, or *Progressing*.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your last part (after I have three more columns to finish). It's not about completeness. For example, if you make pizzas, it takes you 2 minutes, and people are ordering pizzas in an irregular manner. Sometimes you'll be ahead, sometimes behind. I want to count how many pizzas you're behind of (best case behind 0)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Would a fraction work, instead of a word? *2/3 complete.* Or, *6/8 complete*.